# Script tag not working

Tags: javascript, java, spring, jsp, tiles

I am creating an application using spring and tiles. I have a general template where all the js and css are loaded. Anyway, there are some script that are only needed on some views, so I put them only where I need them. But it doesn't work

there are some code

general-template.xml

```
<tiles-definitions>

<definition name="template.general" template="/WEB-INF/view/templates/general.jsp">
    <put-list-attribute name="styles">
        <add-attribute value="/media/css/materialize.css" />
        <add-attribute value="/media/css/style.css" />
        <add-attribute value="/media/css/custom-style.css" />
    </put-list-attribute>
    <put-list-attribute name="scripts">
        <add-attribute value="/media/js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js" />
        <add-attribute value="/media/js/materialize.js" />
        <add-attribute value="/media/js/plugins/perfect-scrollbar.min.js" />
        <add-attribute value="/media/js/plugins.js" />
    </put-list-attribute>
</definition>
```

general.jsp

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

<tiles:importAttribute name="styles"/>
<tiles:importAttribute name="scripts"/>
<tiles:importAttribute name="page_scripts" ignore="true"/>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
<head>
    <c:forEach var="css" items="${styles}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<c:url value="${css}"/>" media="screen,projection">
    </c:forEach>

    <c:forEach var="script" items="${scripts}">
        <script src="<c:url value="${script}"/>"></script>
    </c:forEach>

    <c:forEach var="script" items="${page_scripts}">
        <script src="<c:url value="${script}"/>"></script>
    </c:forEach>


</head>

<body>
    <div id="main">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <section id="content">
                    <tiles:insertAttribute name="body" />
            </section>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

tile.xml

```
<tiles-definitions>
<definition name="solution/list" extends="template.general">
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/view/solution/list.jsp" />
    <put-list-attribute name="page_scripts">
        <add-attribute value="/media/js/plugins/jquery.dataTables.js" />
    </put-list-attribute>
</definition>
</tiles-definitions>
```

list.jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

<table id="solutionList" class="responsive-table display" cellspacing="0">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Descripción</th>
    </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
    <c:forEach var="solution" items="${solutions}">
        <tr>
            <td>${solution.solutionName}</td>
            <td>${solution.description}</td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</tbody>
</table>

<script>
$('solutionList').dataTable({
    responsive : true
});
</script>
```

why when I run this application the script in list.jsp doesn't load? also, chrome devtools marks the line with 'failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404'.

Comment: so the page doesn't exist if you have 404 error, maybe bad path?

Comment: I mean, the page loads properly, but not the script. And the chrome devtools marks only the script line with that error

Comment: only in Chrome? try other browser

Comment: I tried with firefox and ie. But same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think and see you didn't select the table

you don't have `#` in `$('solutionList').dataTable({
    responsive : true
});`

so correct to `$('#solutionList').dataTable({
    responsive : true
});`

Comment: that's righ. Thanks

Comment: just a typo or you didn't notice, no problem, I wish you less mistakes